# File.exists() returns true but File.isFile() says false

Tags: java, macos, file, operating-system

In my project I have a text file with some configuration data that is needed by my application to run on Jetty. I copied this config data in a text file and started the application. But application fails at one condition that is :

```
if(File.exists() && File.isFile()){
...
}
```

I debugged and found `File.exists()` returns `true` always whereas `File.isFile()` is coming `false`. I have no idea what is happening here. I am suspecting its something related to mac os.

Any one has any idea about this?

Comment: what language? objective-c? swift? C++?

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: I have edited your question. Next time please please tag the language and format the code as code.

Comment: [File.isFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) "Returns: true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file;" so the `File.exists()` is redundant. "A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. "

Comment: instead of testing the file, can you just try to open the file for read and use exceptions?